# Recorded macro does not work on chart object

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I recorded the following macro :

```
Sheets("Rejets Techniques TGC").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graphique 1").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='Données'!$EU$68:$IJ$68"
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Données'!$EU$1:$IJ$1"
```

However when I try to lauch it I get this error (translated from french):

```
Execution error '-2147024809 (80070057)'
There is no element with this name
```

How can this be? if there was no graph named this way I wouldn't have been able
to record it.
(yes I'm running it from the good sheet)

Thanks.

Comment: Which line raises the error?

Comment: ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graphique 1").Activate

Comment: Have you tried to use Gaffi's answer below? I tested it, and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what it comes down to: Your chart is not an object *on* the sheet, it *is* the sheet.

So while you use `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graphique 1").Activate` to start your code, there are no `ChartObjects` found in your sheet, because the sheet is the `Chart`. So here's how you get around it:

```
Dim CO As Variant
Set CO = ActiveSheet
CO.Axes(xlCategory).Select
CO.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='Données'!$ET$68:$IJ$68"
CO.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Données'!$ET$1:$IJ$1"
```

And this should work just fine. I noticed that when I looked at the chart tab, I couldn't get into any cells. This is not abnormal, but it is not the most common way (that I see) to create the chart. To verify, I added a [watch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/frice/archive/2005/10/27/485692.aspx) on the `ActiveSheet` and saw that it was indeed a chart (of type `Object/Graph2`) with all the normal chart methods available to it.

From there, I just plugged in your code, converting to the `CO` variable (but yours should still work using `ActiveSheet` across the board), and ran with no errors.

---

As a side note, using `ActiveSheet` is not always effective, and it is generally better to explicitly call the sheet, i.e. `Set CO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rejets Techniques TGC")`

Comment: ChartObjects Count return 0 (on all sheets) (but I can see the chart)

Comment: Yes, look I edited the question, I added a sheet selection before the macro.

Comment: @sliders_alpha Let me ask you another few things... Did you create the charts yourself, or did they come from another source? Is the .xls/xlsx/xlsm/etc file in the 2007 file format, or was it created in/for a different version of Excel?

Comment: It came from an other source, I can see that it's a "Excel 97-2003" xls files, does it matter?

Comment: Ok, however it contains confidential data, I'm going to write a script that is going to replace the 3 years of data by dummy data, I'll give it to you tomorow

Comment: well thank you. kind of weird that microsoft "record macro" wrote non-working code

Comment: @sliders_alpha Agreed. Sorry I can't provide more insight into that specific problem. Perhaps it's a bug?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Check if the active sheet is the one that contaisn the chart. Or use the sheet name in code to run it from any sheet.

2 - Check if the good sheet contains the chart with exact "Graphique 1" name. Maybe there's an underline, like "Graphique_1", or no space "Graphique1"...

Comment: It does the same thing when using the name of the sheet, in properties the graph is name "graph2", using this name produce the same result

Comment: And to awnser more precisly, Graphique_1 and Graphique1 do the same thing.

Comment: To follow up on a different lead, @sliders_alpha: can you check the `Layout` tab under `Chart Tools` section (not sure if these are labeled the same in French) when you have `Graphique 1` selected in the workbook? In the `Properties` section, there should be a `Chart Name` box. Does this match the name you are using in VBA?

Comment: In Chart Tools>layout>properties box I can read "graph name : Rejets Techniques TGC".
However this name produce the same result "no element with such a name"

Comment: Maybe the graph as the same name as the sheet? here look at this : http://s23.postimg.org/e3n9zeb6y/rejet_Tech_TGC.jpg